# Cross-Document Messaging between two windows or tabs, NOT IFrames

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, cross-domain

I have put together a Cross-Document Messaging implementation between a site and an iframe.  It woks great.  But I desire to communicate **between tabs**, not iframes.

Here is the code I have, for the iframe communication in 2 parts.  The first is the Master page and the other is the remote or slave page.

So, MASTER page here...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>Cross-Document Messaging Receiver</title>

 <!-- <script type='text/javascript' src='js/xDocMess.js'></script> -->

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/xDocMess.css"> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function sendMessage() {
        //select the iframe containing the message receiver remote script
        var remoteframe = document.getElementById("remotepage");

        //Get the users message from the message input box
        var message = document.getElementById("message").value;

        //Check that the message is not blank
        if (message !== "") {
        remoteframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, 'http://localhost:8081');
        }
        else {
             alert("You cannot send a blank message!");   
        }
    }

 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Cross-Domain Messaging Example</h1>
 <div id="controls">
     <label>Enter your message to be sent to the iframe: </label>
     <input type="text" id="message" />
     <button id="sendmessage" onclick="sendMessage();">Send Message</button>
     <p>(Note: Only alphanumeric characters will be printed!)</p>
 </div>
 <h3>Remote Script iframe</h3>
 <iframe id="remotepage" src="http://localhost:8081/remote.html"></iframe>
</body>
```

And now, the REMOTE site here...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>Remote Receiver</title>


 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">

 <style type='text/css'>
   body {
   font-family: sans-serif; 
   padding: 10px;    
   }
   h3 {
       padding-bottom: 5px;
   }
   #messages {
    font-size: small;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    padding-top: 10px;          
   }

 </style>
 <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
  window.onload=function(){
    function receiver(message) {
    //get the message container html element (in this case, the messages div)
    var messagecontainer = document.getElementById("messages");
    var trusteddomain = "http://localhost:8081";

    //Get the time of message receipt
    var currenttime = new Date();
    //format the time into a user readable format
    var formattedtime = currenttime.getHours() + ":" + currenttime.getMinutes() + ":" + currenttime.getSeconds();


    var msgcontent = message.data;
    //check the content of the message only contains letters and numbers to prevent xss attacks
    if (msgcontent.match(/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/)) {
        messagecontainer.innerHTML += "message received @ " + formattedtime + ": " + message.data + "<br />";
    } else {
        messagecontainer.innerHTML += "Illegal characters found in the message received @ " + formattedtime + ". Message rejected<br/>";
    }
   }
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h3>Messages Received:</h3>
  <div id="messages"></div>  
</body>
</html>
```

The solution lies in how to call a `window.open` instead of invoking the IFRAME in the MASTER:  `<iframe id="remotepage" src="http://localhost:8081/remote.html"></iframe>` and changing the sendmessage code line:
 `var remoteframe = document.getElementById("remotepage");` 
and be able to pass messages to the window.  I have a mental block there...

Any help would be appreciated...

TIA

Dennis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, I believe all you need to do is name your window when you call window.open and then use this reference in your code just like you would the contentWindow of an iframe:

```
var myWindow = window.open('newTab.html');
myWindow.postMessage('You\'re a nice looking window', 'http://yourtargetdomain.com');
```

You would then put the 'message' handler inside the newTab.html document

```
window.addEventListener('message', function (event) { 
    // security check ...
    console.log('message: ' + event.data); 
});
```

Comment: Can you give an example of that?  You see, the way that you get a hook with the IFRAME is to refer to something in that window as in the sendmessage function:  var remoteframe = document.getElementById("remotepage");

Comment: I've updated my answer with a little more detail. Does this answer your question about usage? I'm not sure I understood you exacly.

Comment: Thank you for your diligence.  I think I understand it now.  Your help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done only using an iFrame.

Page, loaded in an iFrame, acts as a proxy, translating message events into localStorage events, and vice-versa.

localStorage is separate for each domain, that's why it can't be implemented in two different tabs.